# Installing Azure IoT Edge on Win10 IoT Core results in boot failure

Tags: windows-iot-core-10, azure-iot-edge

I'm following standard steps to install Azure IoT Edge on an AMD64 (Intel Celeron J1900) embedded PC. I'm running Windows 10 IoT Core build 17763.253 (latest LTSC version) and using [offline install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-windows#offline-installation) via remote PowerShell to work around some network issues (I was getting `InvalidOperation` exceptions from HTTP file download requests in PowerShell).

```bsh
[192.168.137.26]: PS C:\Data\Users\Administrator\Documents> Deploy-IoTEdge -ContainerOs Windows -OfflineInstallationPath C:\Data\Users\Administrator\Documents
```

```
The container host is on supported build version 17763.
Skipping VC Runtime installation on IoT Core.
Using IoT Edge from C:\Data\Users\Administrator\Documents\microsoft-azure-iotedge.cab
Committing changes, this will cause a reboot on success. If this is the first time installation, run "Initialize-IoTEdge" after the reboot completes.
```

Then the system reboots, shows a quick progress bar that says "Loading files...", and then **goes to a black screen**. After several minutes of sitting there, it goes into the spinning-gears animation, which Bing tells me is for a system update but from which it never exits. No increase in the progress bar, nothing.

I did pull out the flash drive and inspect it on my PC. The `C:\ProgramData\iotedge` folder was correctly created during the install process, but that's all I was able to deduce. I'm not sure if there's a way to extract helpful logs from a flash drive or what I should do now.

What am I missing?

*Note: [Issue posted on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/1617) as well.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command to view the logs.

```
. {Invoke-WebRequest -useb aka.ms/iotedge-win} | Invoke-Expression; Get-IoTEdgeLog
```

If the IoT Edge Security Manager is not running, you may try to check the config.yaml which is located in C:\ProgramData\iotedge folder.

More common issues troubleshooting please see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot).

Comment: I get an `InvalidOperationException` for any use of `Invoke-WebRequest` (even to known good URLs) although pinging a known server like `8.8.8.8` works just fine. So all that to say, I can't call `Get-IoTEdgeLog` after the install -- do you want me to run it _before_ the install, i.e. on a vanilla Win10 IoT Core system? I don't expect it would return anything? (And after the install, the system doesn't boot so I can't open a remote PowerShell session anyways.)

Comment: You can use [ETW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/eventtracing) to trace the event logs on Windows IoT Core. And you can also try to find the update logs in folder C:/Data/Logfiles .

Comment: The first option doesn't quite apply in this scenario since I can't connect to the device after rebooting. Can I send the logs from the IoT Edge Runtime to a file automatically, via steps I could take _before_ the install & automatic restart, so that I could review that file on my USB drive _after_ the failed reboot?
The second option seems like the only thing available to me. I can take a look at it. Would that give me a reason for why the screen stays black for several minutes & why the gears animation starts up? Or would it only record what's going on during that gears animation?

Comment: You may find some errors in the log from the update, but it may not give you a reason for why the device can not boot normally. Another way is to use [WinDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/windowsdebugger), it provides a powerful tool to debug Windows IoT Core.

Comment: There seemed to be no update errors but the device did not boot normally. Will try to use WinDbg and see if that yields further insight. By the way, the device I'm using is the [Axiomtek GOT5153W-834](https://us.axiomtek.com/Default.aspx?MenuId=Products&FunctionId=ProductView&ItemId=7596&C=GOT5153W-834&upcat=265) if that helps.

Comment: It is not suggested prototype board. I'm not sure if that helps. I have no this device to test. Please try with that and tell me if WinDbg works on this board.